# Pandas merge depending on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, where the first `df1` contains sales data like

```
Item    Revenue    Date
ring    200        2018-05-21
led     51         2018-09-18
ring    600        2018-12-25
```

and the second `df2` contains sellers assignation for every item. Note that assignation may change in time and the history is preserved

```
Item    Seller    Since_when
led     Mike      2018-01-01
ring    John      2018-01-01
ring    Mike      2018-12-01
```

The idea is to merge both dataframes on `Item` by a date rule so the sale is assigned to the seller who actually sold the item in that moment, resulting

```
Item    Revenue    Date          Seller
ring    200        2018-05-21    John
led     51         2018-09-18    Mike
ring    600        2018-12-25    Mike (Mike started selling rings on December)
```

Is there a way to tell `pd.merge` to take the newest row of the second dataframe?

**Edit**

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

m1 = pd.DataFrame([['ring', 200, 2018, 5, 21], ['led', 51, 2018, 9, 18], ['ring', 600, 2018, 12, 25]])
m1.columns = ['item', 'revenue', 'año', 'mes', 'dia']

m1['date'] = m1['año'].astype(str) + '-' + m1['mes'].astype(str) + '-' + m1['dia'].astype(str)

m2 = pd.DataFrame([['led', 'Mike', '2018-01-01'], ['ring', 'John', '2018-01-01'], ['ring', 'Mike', '2018-12-01']])
m2.columns = ['item', 'persona', 'fecha']

m = (pd.merge_asof(m1.sort_values('date'), m2.sort_values('fecha'),
                   by='item', left_on='date', right_on='fecha')
       .drop(columns='fecha'))
```

Comment: I also gotta say that `by` parameter can't handle floats at the moment. Strings and ints are ok as far as I tested. This discover took me about 1 hour of googling :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a join on a combination of exact keys and nearest keys (in the past), use [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html). The default direction is `'backward'`.

```
import pandas as pd

m = (pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('Date'), df2.sort_values('Since_when'),
                   by='Item', left_on='Date', right_on='Since_when')
       .drop(columns='Since_when'))
```

#### Output: `m`

```
   Item  Revenue       Date Seller
0  ring      200 2018-05-21   John
1   led       51 2018-09-18   Mike
2  ring      600 2018-12-25   Mike
```

Comment: `'NoneType' object is not callable`. Let me update to show my code.

Comment: @Javier convert your dates to datetimes for both DataFrames, i.e. `m1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(m1.date)`

Comment: Holy conversion! Take your check, admirable Python master.